# How can grant a user for create Trigger in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to grant to special user for create tigger in sql server, but i dont know do it. how can i grant to special user to create a tigger (not execute , for create ).
thanks

Comment: Please follow the link 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms178569.aspx

Comment: I don't know how SQL Server works here, but according to ANSI SQL only the table owner is allowed to create triggers for a table.

Comment: To create a DML trigger requires `ALTER` permission on the table or view on which the trigger is being created. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx